# Why is my R function deleting repeat values in the .csv output?

Tags: r, function, lapply

This is my first post. I just started programming 2 weeks ago because my research lab needed the skill set in the group. We are extracting data that is not delimited from software and so cut-and-paste ends up with values with random spaces that requires hours to clean up. So I wrote this code where I cleaned up the data in Word and then copied to clipboard. I assign that the clipboard contents to a variable.

So for example if the original raw data looks like this:

```
 Component                                        WBC                              RBC                            Hemoglobin                    
Latest Ref Rng & Units                           3.90 - 12.70 K/uL                4.60 - 6.20 M/uL               14.0 - 18.0 g/dL              
9/11/2017                                        7.16                             4.71                           13.3 (L)                      
3/20/2017                                        5.80                             4.31 (L)                       12.7 (L)                      
2/6/2017                                         6.10                             3.74 (L)                       11.3 (L)                      
1/30/2017                                        6.59                             4.18 (L)                       12.7 (L)                      
1/26/2017                                        7.40                             7.40 (L)                       12.1 (L)
```

I clean it up in Word to copy to clipboard the following:

```
 Component                                        WBC                              RBC                            Hemoglobin                    
9/11/2017                                        7.16                             4.71                           13.3                       
3/20/2017                                        5.80                             4.31                        12.7                       
2/6/2017                                         6.10                             3.74                        11.3                       
1/30/2017                                        6.59                             4.18                        12.7                       
1/26/2017                                        7.40                             7.40                        12.1
```

Then I run the following function I created once I assign `readClipboard()` to an object:

```
   cbclabs.R <- function (x){ 
            trimcbc <- strsplit(trimws(x), " ")
             removespace <- c("&", "")
           unlisted <- unlist(lapply(trimcbc, setdiff, removespace))
            cbcmatrix <- matrix(unlisted, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
             return(write.csv(cbcmatrix, file = "cbc.csv"))
             }
```

But unfortunately, the csv file skips repeated values per row at some point in this code so the output looks like:
[image]

I want it to not skip repeat values and create outputs that look like this:
[image]

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: See my answer below.  You can do the `Word` cleanup in `r` too.  I'll add that if you want.

Comment: Yes, how would I do a word cleanup? I have a few other questions, but I'll post them as separate questions! This is so amazing! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: It looks like all you're doing is keeping the first number with digits in each of your columns, so modify the columns like `as.numeric(gsub("(\\d*\\.\\d*).*", "\\1", df$column))`.  Fill `df$column` with the name of your dataframe and column.  Look at `mutate_all` if you're using `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can simplify that a bit:

**For Original Clipboard Data**

```
library(tidyverse) # add pipe `%>%` operator
t(sapply(strsplit(readClipboard(), " "), c)) %>% write.csv("cbc.csv")
```

Or just:

```
write.csv(t(sapply(strsplit(readClipboard(), " "), c)), "cbc.csv")
```

**Edit: For New Clipboard Data**

```
write.csv(t(sapply(strsplit(readClipboard(), "\\s+"), c)), "cbc.csv")
```

Assuming you copy from the "C" in the top left to the 1 in the bottom right.

Comment: Someone edited the original data you had posted (which worked with `readClipboard()`.  Can you provide what you originally posted, or I'll work on what you have now.

Comment: cbclabs.R <- function (x){ 
  trimcbc <- strsplit(trimws(x), " ")
  removespace <- c("&", "")
  unlisted <- unlist(lapply(trimcbc, setdiff, removespace))
  cbcmatrix <- matrix(unlisted, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
  return(write.csv(cbcmatrix, file = "cbc.csv"))
}

Comment: "I assign readClipboard() to an object".  Post this object, but one of those two codes should work anyway

Comment: Thanks Tunn! This was very helpful! I really appreciate it!